# how to remove &zwnj from string in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am learning python in my classes. I have started with web scraping using beautiful soup and is stuck at a website where `<i>"&zwnj"<i>` is used. In python `<i>"&zwnj"<i>` is coming as boxes. How can I remove these boxes from the string? I know they are space, but somehow I am not able to find a proper answer.

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: its is basically scraper code for beautiful soup. nothing fancy. i am using mobile so cannot copy paste here. but the website i am trying to scrape is:- http://www.prajasakti.com/Article/Nellor/1894078 if you inspect element, you will see text on page has this &zwnj. thanks for help.

Comment: @YoutubeTester, that it's "nothing fancy" is irrelevant. How can we possibly help you improve your code if we can't see it? And if you can't be bothered to include your code because you're "using mobile", why should we spend any time on your problem? You should be willing to invest at least as much time into this question as we are.

Comment: @chris thanks for your help buddy. I really appreciate your efforts in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution use the replace function.

```
replace("&zwnj","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string_without_unwanted_text = "".join(string_with_unwanted_text.split("&zwnj"))
```